# Processing array values by simple word count

Tags: php

Is there an elegant way to process array values in a way that allows to use simple word count instead of strlen() or loosing myself with str_word_count -> array_count_values etc.

For example I would like to keep only array values that are containing x words.

For now I'm using.

```
<?php
class Functions
{
    public function processArray($array,$max,$min)
{
        foreach ($array as $value)
        {
        /* char count */
            if (strlen($value) < $max AND strlen($value) > $min) 
        /* word count */
            if (str_word_count($value,0) < $max AND str_word_count($value,0) > $min)
        {
        $array2[] = $value;
        }
    }
return $array2;
    }
}
$input = file_get_contents("files/scrape.txt");
$array = explode(".",$input);
$process = new Functions;
$output = implode(". ",$process->processArray($array,150,50));
print $output;
?>
```

Comment: Sorted. Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

using [**callbacks**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)    (**from PHP 5.4**)

```
function processArray($array,$func)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        if($func($value)){
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

processArray($array, function($a){
    return strlen($a) < 150 && strlen($a) > 50;
});
```

using [**array_filter**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (**from PHP 5.4**)

```
   array_filter($array, function($a){
        return strlen($a) < 150 && strlen($a) > 50;
   });
```

or (**from PHP 5**)

```
function check($a){
   return strlen($a) < 150 && strlen($a) > 50;
}

array_filter($array, 'check');
```

Comment: Thanks for your anserws but I'm not looking for other ways to use strlen but too replace it with function that will allow me to count words instead of single characters.

Comment: what about [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)?

Comment: I have a random loooong string as an input so to process it I have to explode that into array. Using str_word_count means that I'll have to process another array (from str_word_count) and then use for example array_count_values and then go all the way back to string... Was hoping for more elegant solution and less spaghetti.